# Unable to install Apache on Oracle Linux (RedHat)

Tags: linux, apache, redhat

I just installed the Oracle Linux (which I understand is some kind of a subversion of RedHat) and as the title says, I have troubles when I try to set up the Apache.

When I type this command (logged in as root):

```
yum install httpd
```

I get this response:

```
Loading "Installonlyn" plugin
Setting up Install Process
Setting up repositories
No Repositories Available to Set Up
Reading repository metadata in from local files
Parsing package install arguments
Setting up repositories
No Repositories Available to Set Up
Reading repository metadata in from local files
No Match for argument: httpd
Nothing to do
```

**UPDATE:**
Output for the *yum repolist* command:

```
[root@localhost suurp6der]# yum repolist
Loading "installonlyn" plugin

usage: yum [options] < grouplist, localinstall, groupinfo, localupdate, resolvedep, erase, deplist, groupremove, makecache, upgrade, provides, shell, install, whatprovides, groupinstall, update, groupupdate, info, search, check-update, list, remove, clean, grouperase >

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -t, --tolerant        be tolerant of errors
  -C                    run entirely from cache, don't update cache
  -c  [config file]     config file location
  -R  [minutes]         maximum command wait time
  -d  [debug level]     debugging output level
  -e  [error level]     error output level
  -y                    answer yes for all questions
  --version             show Yum version and exit
  --installroot=[path]  set install root
  --enablerepo=[repo]   enable one or more repositories (wildcards allowed)
  --disablerepo=[repo]  disable one or more repositories (wildcards allowed)
  -x [package], --exclude=[package]
                        exclude package(s) by name or glob
  --obsoletes           enable obsoletes processing during updates
  --noplugins           disable Yum plugins
```

How could I fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: what is output of "yum repolist " command  in your OS??

Comment: It was too big for the comments section. I added it above.

Comment: Okey. please provide me output of "yum list".

Comment: As I observed you don't have any repositories, you need to configure public repo.

Comment: I guess I'll try to do that. I'll ask if I need some help with that. (BTW, the _yum list_ output was way too big to be posted here.)

Comment: Okey, use this to configure public repo : https://blogs.oracle.com/wim/entry/setting_up_oracle_linux_6

Answer (score 0):

Because here mention clearly "No Repositories Available to Set Up"
First setup local and remove repository and execute below comman :

`yum list | grep httpd`

Then you get httpd-*

and install :

`yum install httpd`